# Creating IF statement inside math.Random function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create code that if we generate number between 20 and 120 and the generated number is >= than 100 then we want to reduce by 20. I dont want to create multiple random numbers..Can someone help ??
my basic math.rand function -

```
function randomNumber(min, max) {
                return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
              }
```

the code i tried to make

```
  randomNumber(20,120);
    if(randomNumber >= 100){
      return randomNumber - 20;
    }
    message.reply(randomNumber);
```

In messages it display function randomNumber(min, max) { etc...

Comment: Why `return`? If you want to reply regardless, then `message.reply(randomNumber - 20);` inside the `if`

Comment: Maybe you want to use the modulo operator (`x % y`)?

Comment: I dont want to make it everytime - 20

Comment: I dont know how to use modulo

Comment: `var rand = randomNumber(20, 120) % 100;`

Comment: What about creating numbers between `20` and `100` in the first place? That would be the same in general case

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky I have some reason to do that...

Comment: Then your code is fine, with the exception of lacking `message.reply`

Comment: @user1438038 `randomNumber(20, 120) % 100` will not subtract 20 if the `number >= 100`. Assume the generated number is 101. Subtracting 20 would land it on 81. Using modulo 100 lands it on 1.

Comment: @3limin4t0r: I was just second-guessing that the modulo operation is, what the OP was actually looking for. But, of course, modulo will not substract 20 from anything.

Answer (score 2):

Store the result of the randomNumber function in a variable like this:

```
  let number = randomNumber(20,120);
  if(number >= 100){
       number -= 20;
  }
  message.reply(number);
```

In JavaScript, you add `()` to run a function. Without those parentheses, you are just returning the code itself. When you state `if(randomNumber >= 100)`, you aren't comparing the value that the function returns, rather the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

When you call randomNumber(20,120) it returns a number, but you don’t put that number in any variable, so it just gets lost. And then you return randomNumber, which is a function, that’s why it prints out the content of the function.

To avoid that, create a variable containing the random number, like so:

```js
let x = randomNumber(20,120);
if(x >= 100){
  x -= 20;
}
message.reply(x);
```

Comment: I think this is what i want, thanks

Comment: wait, how could i get number 15 ??? it just gave me 15... how ?!

Comment: @Robert To help the community and yourself easily find the optimal answer to this question, you may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Oskar's answer. :)

Comment: @bordeaux what he’s saying is that he doesn’t understand how he got the result 15, not that he wants 15

Comment: thanks @bordeaux, anyway i tried other code and it work properly, so im done with this, thanks ALL !

Answer (score 1):

Just save the result of your function in a variable and then check if that variable is `>= 100` and if it is reduce it by 20 using a simple ternary operator.

```js
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

number = randomNumber(20,120);

number = (number < 100) ? number : number -20;

console.log(number);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i am using it and it works